#  Creating Relation for Multiple Parent Tables linking to single table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-5

I have two tables (Person and Business, both with a unique ID column). Both are different, capturing an individual (Person) and one capturing legal entities (Business). But what is common is their address, so the Address table contains two fields, fkEntityID and fkEntityTypeID, that will relate to table Person as follows:

Person Table -> Address Table Person ID = fkEnityID and an enum Person = fkEntityTypeID

Business Table - >Address Table Business ID = fkEnityID and an enum Business = fkEntityTypeID

How do I define the relationship in code first using an enum as part of the foreign key?

```
 // Relationships
            this.HasOptional(t => t.Person)
                .WithMany(t => t.Addresses)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.fkEntityID);
```

Comment: It may be better to have the entities store an `AddressID` - or to implement separate columns for each referenced entity and a check constraint in the database that ensures strictly one of them is non-NULL.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, the problem is that there are more tables(Parent Tables like the Person/Business/User/Supplier eg that will use the address table, this will make the address table ending up with lots of columns, does EF not like this kind of approach , is my DB design incorrect for using EF?

Comment: You can take EF out of the picture entirely. It's not possible to declare a correct Foreign Key constraint in SQL, based on your current structure. As I say, one way out of this may be to reverse the relationship so that the entities reference the address table rather than the other way around.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed that this might be the solution

Comment: EF follows same rules as DB. If you cannot create FK constraint in the database you also cannot map it in EF.